# How does the money system work in CSGO?

Tags: steam, counter-strike-global-offensive

How does the money system work? How much money is provided for winning/losing and kills?

Is there differences between T and CT side for money/cost? Guns will give me different rewards, how is this determined? For example the AWP will reward $100, but a grenade kill is $300. Would a molotov kill be the same? A knife kill?

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes guns give me different rewards"?  Do you mean the same guns give different money, or different guns give different money?

Comment: Oops my apologies, different guns give different money.

Comment: According to the CS Wiki, kills with different guns (or a knife) do give different rewards: http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Money#Counter-Strike:_Global_Offensive

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Money

All information below only applies to Classic Modes (Casual and Competitive) as Arsenal and Deathmatch do not use money. The Money cap in Casual Mode has been changed to $10000 as opposed to $16000 in Competitive.

**Rewards**

**Kill rewards**

[image]

**Objective rewards**

- In Bomb Defusal, defusing or planting the bomb awards a $300 bonus for the player that defused / planted.
- In Competitive Hostage Rescue, all Counter-Terrorists receive a $600 reward for picking up a hostage.
- In Competitive Hostage Rescue, all Counter-Terrorists receive a $600 reward for rescuing a hostage.
- In Casual Hostage Rescue, all Counter-Terrorists receive a $500 reward for picking up a hostage.
- In Hostage Rescue, the player who picks up the hostage receives a $300 bonus.
- In Hostage Rescue, the player who rescues the hostage receives a $1000 bonus.

**Round end rewards**

[image]

**Penalties**

- When the player injures hostages, the player will receive a -$30 penalty for every point of damage dealt to the hostage.
- In competitive mode, teamkilling will result in a penalty of -$300.
- To discourage "denying" (prevent the enemy from getting a kill award by committing suicide), players who committed suicide or disconnected mid-game will cause an enemy player to receive compensation equal to the kill award that could have been gained.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1G835.png)
- In Bomb Defusal, surviving Terrorists will not receive any round-end money if the round is lost by running out of time.